# how to substract two sums based on different field values in one table (view)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

example: i need the numbers of which the sum of the amount where id = 1 is not equal of the sum of the amount where id <> 1, together with the id's and difference.
The table (view in this case) may look like this:

```
NUMBER   AMOUNT   ID

0001     500       1
0001     500       2
0002     400       3
0003     299       1
0003     300       3
0003     300       3
```

Many thanks for your help on this one.

Comment: what rdbms are you using?  if sql server, what version?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), what is your desired result?

Comment: sqlserver 2000 i've tried to use a join on the same table with aliases

Comment: result may look like this: number 0002 difference 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this query you can get sum of amounts grouped by number, with ID equals 1 and ID not equals 1.

```
SELECT NUMBER
, SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Equals1
, SUM(CASE WHEN ID <> 1 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS NotEquals1
FROM DataTable
GROUP BY NUMBER
```

If this is you expected, use following query to get difference amounts grouped by number.

```
SELECT NUMBER, (Equals1 - NotEquals1) AS DifferenceAmount
FROM
(
    SELECT NUMBER
    , SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Equals1
    , SUM(CASE WHEN ID <> 1 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS NotEquals1
    FROM DataTable
    GROUP BY NUMBER
) AS GroupedTable
WHERE Equals1 <> NotEquals1
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reaction, @Prassana answer works best in my case, i only would like to add one more information (date) field in the result. How can i do that without changing the result?

Comment: sorry i misspelled your name in the above comment

Comment: If you need to group by date as well, put it in both SELECT's and GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    MyView.Number,
    MyView.Amount - D.OverOneTotal AS Difference
FROM
    MyView
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
        Number,
        SUM(Amount) OverOneTotal
    FROM
        MyView
    WHERE
        ID > 1
    GROUP BY 
        Number) D ON MyView.Number = D.Number
WHERE
    MyView.ID = 1
    AND MyView.Amount <> D.OverOneTotal
```

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT JOIN` and not `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @AndriyM if it was an `INNER JOIN` then all Numbers for which there was only one record would be omitted from the results.

Comment: I see, thanks. I don't think there would be any point displaying that row, although that's merely my (possibly incorrect) interpretation of the question, of course. However, your query wouldn't display that lonely record anyway, because your WHERE clause (the `MyView.Amount <> D.OverOneTotal` part, in particular) effectively turns your left join into an inner join.